# connect two or more machines using SAML

Tags: saml

I need to connect two or more machines using SAML(Security assertion markup language) to gain access to the documents of the other machine , using a link or any other mechanism . If anyone has prior experience in SAML please guide me

Answer (score 1):

You need to install a STS (Security Token Service) that supports SAML e.g. ADFS, OpenAM, Shibboleth.

Then you hook up the application that allows you to view the documents.

So the path is:

User -> Application -> STS -> Authenticate -> Gain access.

Comment: I am working on an intranet application where a 3rd party user has to be given rights to access documents of my application or use my application . Can IBM tivoli be used to achieve the functionality ? please guide me

Comment: Sorry don't know anything about Tivoli.